# Error code: 2103 Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, connection

**Problem:** I have database containing several lines of longtext fields to insert into a table containing 4,960,372 characters and keep getting **"Error code: 2103 Lost connection to MySQL server during query"**.

We are trying to restore a 16GB MySQL database, the table contains email header + email code.

Have exported form original database using: `mysqldump kayako < C:\temp\kayako.sql`

**Have Tried several ways to restore:**
1. Restore backup from file into SQL and set the max allowed packed size to 1GB using `mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=1G --opt -uroot -p -hpassword databasename > yourbackup.sql`

1. Using MySQL Workbench, MySQL Maestro
2. Splitting up the output file and importing each (only fails on these long inserts)

Please help, its so frustrating.

**Are there other ways to handle excessively long field inserts.**

info:

```
Product = Kayako Fusion
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
max_allowed_packet = 1G
Columns:
   parserlogdataid  int(11) AI PK
   parserlogid      int(11)
   contents         longtext
```

Answer (score 0):

My very first idea would be to have a look at some timer (wait_timeout seems to be a good start).
Standard configuration of MySQL close connexion after a given time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a hardware (eg RAM) issue: check the condition of your network. Create the same database + table on a localhost server (eg WAMP) and try if the query works there. (Are you saying that you can;t even run 1 query?  Check the attribute field of database, maybe change it from VARCHAR to text.

Remove code for the banner, counter and who's online will reduce it by another 8 queries per page.  Turn category counts off.  cache the configuration table (contribution), page cache (contribution).  Read the thread on Store Speed Optimization. 
Ref http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/321393-2103-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query/

I also recommend reading https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html